# Error: TS2304: Cannot find name 't'. while running the angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

[image]

I generated a some spec files using https://www.npmjs.com/package/gentest
And I am able to run tests without any errors. Its just when I serve the app I get these.

`webpack-dev-server -d --progress --colors --inline --config configs/webpackConfig/webpack.local.js --port 3000`

**base.service.spec.ts**

```
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {BaseService} from './base.service';

describe('BaseService', () => {
  let service;

  const httpClient: any = {
    // mock properties here 
  }

  const loggerService: any = {
    // mock properties here 
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new BaseService(httpClient,loggerService);
  });

  it('should run #postData()', async () => {
    // const result = postData(url, data, headers, apimKey);
  });

  it('should run #getData()', async () => {
    // const result = getData(url, headers, apimKey);
  });

  it('should run #deleteData()', async () => {
    // const result = deleteData(url, headers);
  });

  it('should run #handleError()', async () => {
    // const result = handleError(operation, result);
  });

  it('should run #postMethod()', async () => {
    // const result = postMethod(url, data, headers);
  });

});
```

Comment: Not sure but maybe they got put off by the image? Maybe improve the question by replacing the image with errors with just the errors as text.

Comment: Also can you show the Webpack config used here?

Comment: Could you show us the base.service.spec.ts and base.service.ts file? It would help to see if there is a typo or a similar error.

Comment: @Francesco I have it in my question details. And even if I remove all of the content in that file i still get errors saying there are invalid characters in that file

Comment: Does the same errors occurr even without gentest? That library is quite old (last publish 5 years ago) and does not look stable as on npm it is stated: "This is a work in progress. Consider it "Stability 1: Experimental" for the time being." So it is quite probable that it is not compatible or triggering errors from the inner library itself.

Comment: @Francesco the issue is only with files generated by gentest. I ended up deleting all spec files generated by it. Now I have to manually write spec files for all the components. :/

Comment: Glad you could solve it!